# Define shifted pdf

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I defined a PDF called dist, for example like this one:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
  Convolve[PDF[NormalDistribution[4, 5], x], 
   PDF[NormalDistribution[3, 1], x], x, t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Is it possible to get also a shifted PDF?
For example

$p_1(x)=dist(x), p_2(x)=dist(x-c)$

where c is a constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transformed distribution should do what you want, e.g.,

```
dist=TransformedDistribution[a u + b,  u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]]
```

so in your case, distributed by your custom PDF. Be aware, while neat, *MMA* fancy-probability features have their limits...